# Chrome Extension: show additional content in an overlay

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a Chrome extension that displays the definition and synonyms of a selected word on double-click. This additional content appears in a div that overlays the active page. I achieve this by appending a div, applying styles, and setting the z-index. Here are fragments to demonstrate my approach:

```
const tooltip = document.createElement("div");
tooltip.className = "extTooltip";
const styles = document.createElement("style");
styles.innerHTML = `...`
document.head.appendChild(styles);
document.body.appendChild(tooltip);
```

The issue is that some styles of my div are overridden by the page styles, despite my use of !important. I wonder if there is a more efficient way to achieve the desired behavior?
[style overridden, example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjlIn.png)
[style overridden, example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TctlC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) CSS rule to reset all rules for an element back to their inial values. From there you can apply your own styling as required.

Here's a simplified working example using `unset`. You would need to investigate which of the possible values, `initial`, `inherit`, `unset`, `revert` or `revert-layer`, is best for your specific use case.

```css
div {
  background-color: #C00;
  color: #EEE;
}

#except-this {
  all: unset;
}
```

```html
<div>Fizz</div>
<div>Buzz</div>
<div id="except-this">Foo</div>
<div>Bar</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This solves my issue perfectly

Comment: No problem, glad to help